# Reactjs Variable inside component is not writable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code not working. Please advice.

```
parent = react.createClass({
     getInitialState: function(){
         return {tags:{}};
     },
     render:function(){
         return <child update={this.updateState}/>
     },
     updateState: function(value){
         existing = this.state.tags;
         existing[0] = value
         // 
         **// Should output value entered in child.**
         console.log("existing") // Actual output is {}

     }
});
child = react.createClass({
     getInitialState: function(){
         return {value:""};
     },
     change: function(event){
         this.setState({value: event.target.value})
     },
     render:function(){
         return <input onBlur={this.update} onChange={this.change}/>
     },
     update: function(){
         this.props.update(this.state.value)
     }
});
```

The code has comments in it explaining issue. Please let me know what mistake is am doing

Updated: added braces around this.updateState.

Answer: I got the mistake. Following line was causing the issue.

```
existing = this.state.tags;
```

above statement assigns this.state.tags's reference to existing.
In reactjs the state is none editable directly we should use this.setState. so we cannot add any data to existing as it is pointing to this.state.tags. So to solve this we will have to create a new reference with state data.

following code is solution to the above problem.

```
 existing = _.extend({}, this.state.tags);// import lodash library in underscore variable
 existing[0] = value;
 conosle.log(existing);
```

Comment: How does `console.log("existing")` output an empty object literal???

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be in the line `return <child update=this.updateState/>`.

If you enclose the update prop like this: `return <child update={this.updateState}/>` you should be able to read out the value of existing with `console.log(existing)`

It wouldn't compile for me until I changed that line. Hope that helps.

Comment: even though i add braces and try to run the code. Still the existing value is not updated.